PBI DAX Calculating number of Holders whose payment value is below the 90th Percentile
I have a table in Power BI with 3 columns:
| Company Code | HOLDER ID | UNPRESENTED SUM
There are multiple holder IDs per company code. I want to calculate the number of holder IDs whose payment value is below the 90th Percentile. I have successfully calculated the 90th Percentile using the below:
PERCENTILE90 = 
PERCENTILE.INC(
    UNPRESENTED[UNPRESENTED SUM],0.90
    )

However, when I try to calculate the number of holders whose values are below the 90th percentile, the measure I get is blank.
I have tried two different ways:
1. METHOD 1
First, a measure to determine if below 90th Percentile:
Is Below 90th Percentile = 
VAR Percentile90 = [PERCENTILE90]
RETURN
IF(
    MAX('UNPRESENTED'[UNPRESENTED SUM]) < Percentile90,
    1,
    0
)

Then, a measure to count the holders:
HOLDERS < 90 = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(UNPRESENTED[HOLDER ID]),
    FILTER(
        UNPRESENTED,
        [Is Below 90th Percentile] = 1
    )
)

This failed.
2. METHOD 2
A calculated column to return 1 or 0 if value is below 90th percentile:
Below 90th? = 
VAR Percentile90 = 
CALCULATE(
    PERCENTILE.INC(
        UNPRESENTED[UNPRESENTED SUM], 0.9
        )
        )
RETURN
IF(
    UNPRESENTED[UNPRESENTED SUM] < Percentile90, 1, 0
    )

and this returned all 0s, which is obviously wrong, as most values should be below the value of 90th percentile.
Any ideas what I am missing?
